# Exiting a for loop that creates divs when reached end of screen

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, responsive, screen-size

I am trying to complete a little exercise that refreshes the page when the big button in the middle is clicked and the little dots change colour. 
I have stopped the page from scrolling so the page is full of dots but I have noticed that the overflow property acts differently on different browsers. Then I thought of another issue, on mobile or tablets the dots will show differently again!
So I'm not sure if this is even possible but the desired result is for the loop to create dots until the screen is full and the button displaying in the middle of the screen.
Could someone please tell me if this idea is possible as I haven't been able to find any similar questions. Or if there is a better way to get my desired result. Also if you have the time could you please briefly explain why as I want to understand how it works and learn from it.
So...
This is the JavaScript

```
var htmlDot = "";
var red;
var green;
var blue;
var rgbColor;


function colourSelect() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
}

for(var i = 1; i<=100; i+=1) {
    red = colourSelect();
    green = colourSelect();
    blue = colourSelect();
    rgbColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
    htmlDot += "<div style=\"background-color:"+ rgbColor + " \"></div>";
}
document.write(htmlDot);
```

This is the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <button id="refresh">Click Me!</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS

```
  body {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#refresh {
    font: 40px bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgb();
}
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
 }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check for offset of every div after appending it in DOM. If the outer most edge that is Offsettop+height goes beyond window.height then stop / return from loop else continue. Simple.

Comment: Although logic is simple implementations is something that may take some efforts.

Comment: I already have headache from those circles. :)

Comment: me too, have been looking at them for so long i see dots when I close my eyes :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

https://jsbin.com/racahapevi/edit?html,css,js,output

Key points:

- Calculate numbers of dots that can fit horizontally
- Calculate total numbers of dots
- Define `<html>`, `<body>` width and height to 100% of the viewport
- overflow: hidden on html, so there will not be scroll
- Add onclick event the button.

Here some code:

```
var numDots = hdots * vdots;

while(numDots--){
    red = colourSelect();
    green = colourSelect();
    blue = colourSelect();
    rgbColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
    htmlDot += "<div class='dot' style=\"background-color:"+ rgbColor + " \"></div>";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to explain your steps and sharing this jsbin. I really appreciate it

Comment: no problem @Jessica, but remember to accept the answer and good luck with the learning process :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 100 for the number of dots you have to figure out how many dots fit in your browser window given the dimensions of the browser window.

```
var w = window.innerWidth; // browser width
var h = window.innerHeight; // browser height
var size = 60; // 50px + 5px + 5px (width or height) + (left or top margin) + (right or bottom margin)
var hdots = Math.floor(w/size); // how many dots fit horizontally
var vdots = Math.floor(h/size); // how many dots fit vertically
var numDots = hdots * vdots;
```